# Sony Bluetooth Headphones connecting but as an "unknown" device with no option to use

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 22.04, headphones, sony

I recently bought a pair of Sony WF-C500 headphones and although they do connect via bluetooth they aren't recognised as an audio device and can't be used for sound output (or mic input).

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I have not installed any extra bluetooth or audio stuff (aside from pacontrol) and have been able to use my computer to connect other bluetooth speakers no problem (cambridge audio amp, portable speaker, Logitech audio adaptor etc).

Are there any additional things I would need to install to get it to sync properly? I haven't found anything saying it is a known issue and I imagine Sony headphones are pretty popular.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe not as popular as you think... There are dozens, maybe hundreds, of similar quality products for half the price, even from well established brands and the vast majority just work in Ubuntu.

Comment: Fair enough, but how do I go about getting it to connect as an audio device?

Comment: I couldn't find anything specific for that model.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to work, this is what I did: make sure it is in proper pairing mode by pushing the button on both sides for 5 seconds.

Then I installed blueman (sudo apt-get install blueman), and the program finds the device and recognizes it as headphones. I simply connected and I could see it both as output and input device in the sound settings.

Comment: It worked for me (Ubuntu 20)

Comment: It was not initially working for me in Ubuntu 20.04. But after pushing the button for few seconds i.e., triggering the pairing mode it got connected.

Comment: Thank you so much - this worked for me. I had to do what you suggested a couple of times. Originally the earphones showed up as "LE_WF-C500" and weren't pairing correctly. This time though, they showed up as "WF-C500" and did pair correctly. By the way, I did not do this through Blueman, just the normal Ubuntu Bluetooth panel in Settings.

Comment: This did not work for me in Ubuntu 22.04 with Sony WI-C100 headphones. **EDIT:** Actually it did, you just have to hold in the pairing button while you are connecting it on your computer.